# LINQ with just a where clause or where plus Any clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to know which of these LINQ queries is more efficient (and how to figure this out). One has all of the logic in the where clause and the other has it half in the where clause and half in the Any clause. In this case, the data is coming from SQL Server. Thanks!

```
return (from c FamilyList
       where c.Persons.Any(cp => cp.Person.PersonID == specificPersonID)
       select c).Any(c => c.StartDate == null || c.StartDate > specificDate);

return (from c FamilyList
       where c.Persons.Any((cp => cp.Person.PersonID == specificPersonID)
       && (c.StartDate == null || c.StartDate > specificDate)
       select c).Any();
```

Comment: I think your closing parenthesis is in the wrong place in the second example. Also, you might want to wrap the `StartDate` clauses in parenthesis in the second example..

Comment: @RufusL Maybe it is `return FamilyList.Any(c => c.Persons.Any(p => p.Person.PersonID == sepecificPersonId) && (c.StartDate == null || c.StartDate > specificDate));` instead?

Comment: Neither of those compile, unless you're using some version of the language that doesn't require `in` in a LINQ query, and in the second one `cp` doesn't exist when you check `cp.StartDate`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good point. In the second example it's comparing the person start date (`cp.StartDate`) to `null` and the family start date (`c.StartDate`) to `specificDate`, so it's a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I was careless when I was editing. I've updated them both

Comment: what provider and store are you using? It would basically come down to the query generated by these, for example in a SQL instance the first query may generate a subselect and further filter wrapping it in another select, whereas the 2nd simply creates a single select...

Comment: The data is coming from SQL Server.

Answer (score -2):

Commenting on above query only.2nd query is efficient since filtering is done only once.First does twice.

Suggestion:Above query is mixed query where it has lamda and query expression.Please use only lamda expression to maintain code consistency

Comment: Okay, I agree with only using lambda expressions and code consistency, but when you have a SQL AND statement, they are evaluated sequentially and both of these linq statements have two clauses which are evaluated sequentially. There is no logical difference, but is there a processing difference between these two?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It depends entirely on how the Linq provider runs the query - if it's generating SQL then even if it does produce redundant `WHERE` clauses any half-decent RDBMS will coalesce the criteria together. If it's running in-memory (Linq-to-Objects) then it won't necessarily be optimized (depends on the JIT) but the computational-complexity is the same.